# Creating expandable buttons/sections with shadow/rounded edges using just one element?

Tags: html, css

Usually when I create buttons using gradients, or sections and buttons using shadow or rounded edges, I use something like the following CSS format to allow the contained content to be any length:

```
#button {
    height: 40px;
}

.button_edge_left {
    float: left;
    width: 4px;
    height: 40px;
    background: url(images/button-left_static.png);
}

.button_middle_cont {
    float: left;
    padding: 12px 10px;
    font: bold 16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    height: 40px;
    background: url(images/button-middle_dynamic.png);
}

.button_edge_right {
    float: left;
    width: 4px;
    height: 40px;
    background: url(images/button-right_static.png);
}
```

Above is my CSS where `.button_edge_left` and `.button_edge_right` act as either end (left/right) of a button and `.button_middle_cont` acts as the middle portion which can expand horizontally.

For good measure, html HTML:

```
<div id="button">
<div class="button_edge_left"></div>
<div class="button_middle_cont">This is a button!</div>
<div class="button_edge_right"></div>
</div>
```

**I'm wondering if there's anyway to remove the two edge classes, and somehow create an element which brings together all three classes?**

Although there's more overhead, this is a lot easier from an editing point of view then having individual static images for each button on a page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS3 allows for multiple background images to be assigned to a single element.

```
#button {
    padding: 12px 10px;
    font: bold 16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    height: 40px;
    background: url(images/button-left_static.png) left top no-repeat, url(images/button-right_static.png) right top no-repeat, url(images/button-middle_dynamic.png);
}
```

Again, this solution is only viable for CSS3 compliant browsers (IE >= 9, Opera >= 10.5, Firefox >= 3.6, Chrome/Safari >= 1.3).

These images stack in the order they are written, therefore the first background image will be the more *foreground* background, and as such you should put your repeating image last.

Comment: Sweet, I'll try this out ASAP. In all honesty, I don't bother with creating fall-backs for redundant browsers for non-consumer targeted sites so CSS3 shan't be an issue :)!

Comment: It works brilliantly, but seems to have a width of 100% (maybe this is the CSS norm, as I've always set widths of parent containers at least, hence it's probably taking the width of `body`) http://jsfiddle.net/Z5jy9/2/, is there anyway to get it to restrict itself to the width of contents inside?

Comment: What you are asking for is referred to as "shrink-wrapping" or "shrink-to-fit", and unfortunately, there is no `shrink-to-fit: true;` attribute in CSS.  There are a few methods for achieving this, each with their own pros and cons.  For the use I am assuming this is for, I would recommend a `display: inline-block;` attribute be added to your stylesheet for the element.  There are other methods, such as `float: left;` and `display: inline;`, the latter of which will not allow you to set a height, however.

Comment: Amazing! Any idea of any downsides I should watch out for with `display: inline-block;`?

Comment: Since listing pros and cons to each method wouldn't be apt for this comment box, I dug up a very nice reference for you to peruse which will hopefully better explain the differences between them, when each is more prudent, and how to counter their drawbacks.  Specific to `inline-block`, you may come to find that multiple similar elements begin to "stack" horizontally on your page, which may or may not be good for your purpose.  http://haslayout.net/css-tuts/CSS-Shrink-Wrap